# Opencart insert Google Maps

Tags: opencart

I'm trying to find file in opencart that I can insert Google map in my site.
Anyone who knows in which file I can insert this code?
(I know that there are modules but I want to try this way )

**----> these are the coords

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
          type="text/javascript"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map"  style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>




  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['Vlachiotis 230 55, Greece', **********,*************, 7],
      ['5is Maiou, Skala 230 51, Greece', **********,*************, 6],


      ['Thales Koutoupi, Skala 230 51, Greece', **********,*************, 4],
      ['EO Spartis Githiou, Githio 232 00, Greece', **********,*************, 5],
      ['Vasileos Georgiou 47, Githio 232 00, Greece', **********,*************, 3],
      ['Petrompei Mavromichali, Githio 232 00, Greece', **********,*************, 2],
      ['Mavrovouni 232 00, Greece', **********,*************, 1]
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 11,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.82, 22.61),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: want you display in which page?

Comment: i want it in home somewhere above the footer

Comment: which OpenCart version are you using ?

Comment: im using opencart 2.1 version .! But im working in 2.9.5 journal theme

Comment: You can add your code in home.tpl file. Go to > catalog > view > theme > default(your theme) > template > common > home.tpl file.

Comment: so i throw in this folder the body only right ?

Comment: okey I Found it  HarnishDesign thanks for ur help !!!